# Db first approach, composite primary key in table, EF not creating entity for that table

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

In Entity framework DB first approach, I have two columns in Db table which are composite primary key. When i am creating an entity framework for that DB, that table is not appearing as entity there.

Answer (score 0):

To create composite primary key you can add the data annotation `[Key, Column(Order = 0)]`

```
public class Person
{
  [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
  public string ID{ get; set; }

  [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
  public int IDTwo { get; set; }
}
```

You can also use Fluent Api.

Comment: I think this solution is for Code first approach, I am using DB first approach of EF,

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Junction table(for implementing Many-to-many relationship) in your database, then in Database First approach, it will not be visible as an entity in the edmx Dig.

Many-to-Many Relationship ([Reference](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx))

The **Student** and **Course** have a Many-to-Many relationship marked by * multiplicity. It means one Student can enroll for many Courses and also, one Course can be taught to many Students.

The database includes the **StudentCourse** joining table which includes the primary key of both the tables ('Student and Course tables'). Entity Framework represents many-to-many relationships by not having the entity set (DbSet property) for the joining table in the CSDL and visual designer. Instead it manages this through mapping.

Note: Entity framework supports many-to-many relationships only when the joining table (StudentCourse in this case) does NOT include any columns other than PKs of both tables. If the join tables contain additional columns, such as DateCreated, then the EDM creates an entity for the middle table as well and you will have to manage CRUD operations for many-to-many entities manually.

---

Also note, that the link(aka Junction) table is not represented as an entity in our mode. when it has no payload ( that is it has no scalar property ). If we had a payload, we shouldn't have the many to many relationship but we should have a fourth entity with one-to-many relationship. For more refer [this](http://%20https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/702890/MVC-Entity-Framework-and-Many-to-Many-Relation)